# JHipster - Using server, embedded or external

Tags: jhipster

when a JHipster app is run, it is using in default an embedded server, as far as I understood it is Undertow.

Questions:
How to configure to use another provided available embedded server (Tomcat for example)?
How to configure to not use an embedded server, but instead an external server like Tomcat?

Cheers

Comment: Nothing specific to Jhipster here, it's purely spring boot configuration by specifying dependencies in pom.xml or build.gradle. Check their doc. Be aware though that using an external server is more complex, you can find many questions about it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

all your need to do is copy and paste your *.war file to your tomcat external server, and run your jhipster app as server root or rename your jhipster war archieve into ROOT.war ( this is a bad way ).

i've done this before when i;m deployed my jhipster app with openshift which is must deployed inside of tomcat 8.